# How to add `scroll` bar to a `div`, when its height as `auto`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my container, there is multiple childrens, one of the 'div' getting appended by content in that.

when the total height of the container(parent) overflows, i would like to add the scroll bar to the `div`

is it possible to do by `css`?

here is the html :

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

Js :

```
var p= "</p>Some testing text</p>";

$('button').click(function(){
    $('.content').append(p);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doesfmnm/3/)

**UPDATE**

I don't want to put the **over-flow to container**, if so my `footer` will hide. i require my user need to see the `add` button always. I can't put my button out side of the `container` again there would be multiple `content` in to the `container`

**UPDATE**

I find a solution by `js` is it possible to made without using `js'?

[jsSolution](http://jsfiddle.net/doesfmnm/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do in CSS. Simply add this CSS rule to `#container`:

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Alternatively add this to show the scroll bar only when necessary:

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

Comment: I don't want to add overflow to `container` see my comments to joseph.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/doesfmnm/2/

```js
var p= "</p>Some testing text</p>";

$('button').click(function(){
    $('.content').append(p);
});
```

```css
 .content{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:300px;
    width:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

Adding a little more explanation to what @Guy3000 said. You're appending (adding after) into an element with the class 'content'. Let's consider what that means for the parent .container class. By adding content into a div inside of the parent, your parent will need to either grow to compensate for the added content, or it will need to have a y-axis scroll that permits content longer than the *height* of the container.

This means you can approach the dilemma you're facing by adding height to the container element, or you can keep a fixed height on the container and have a frame with a y-axis scroll bar contain the added content.

Comment: I don't want to put the over flow to container, if so my `footer` will hide. i require my user need to see the `add` button always. I can't put my button out side of the `container` again there would be multiple `content` holder too..

Comment: simply change the class name. Change the container css to content. The content needs to have a static hide that can handle the overflow.

Comment: this what the problem, because since the `content` with static height, the add button in the down. i require `static` height avoided solution. if not possible even using `jQuery`

Comment: Try typing that again. The english is improper.

Comment: I am applying this to html side bar. while i apply the `static` height to `content` the `add` button hides. as well  some time even there is not `filled` content with `content` `div` the `add` button unnecessarly in the down..that's wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70503/discussion-between-joseph-casey-and-3gwebtrain).

Comment: Idk what you're asking. You have to be able to explain your problem.

Comment: See this question: not quite what you want but close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949572/how-to-make-a-div-stay-at-the-bottom-of-another-div-that-scrolls

Comment: This will not help for me, it has no `dynamic` content updates.

Comment: Have a look in to my solution using `css` and `html` - finds any issue, let me know. thanks for your time with me!.

Comment: That's only working with `chrome` other browser is not.. I am starting again from first!

Comment: You could user a server-side language to add the content dynamically upon click, but you won't be able to do it with css.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i find :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="up">Text<br />Text<br />Text<br /></div>
    <div id="down">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="misc"><button>Add</button></div>
</div>
```

css :

```
#container { width: 300px; height: 300px; border:1px solid red;display:table;}
#up { background: green;display:table-row;height:0; }
#down { background:pink;display:table-row; overflow-y:auto}
.misc {
    display:table-row;
    background:gray;
    height:30px;
}

.content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/xrebB/106/)

js solution :

[http://jsfiddle.net/doesfmnm/4/](http://JS%20solution)